# Does OpenThread allow multiple CoAP secure connections?

Tags: openthread

I try to initialize 2 DTLS sessions with 2 different peers. The first `otCoapSecureConnect` returns `OT_ERROR_NONE`, the second one returns `OT_ERROR_INVALID_STATE`.  Does OpenThread allow multiple CoAP secure connections ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current CoAP Secure APIs in OpenThread only supports a single active session.